50s or 60s sci-fi movie featuring scientists who learn to operate an abandoned flying saucer
This is a 50s or 60s movie featuring a bunch of scientists who learn to operate an abandoned flying saucer that's found in an uninhabited area. The film ends with the scientists flying the craft.
Does anyone know the title of this movie? Sorry if I can't give more details; I watched this movie a long time ago.

Was this black & white or in colour?

The Bamboo Saucer from 1968?
From Wikipedia:

The Bamboo Saucer is an independently made 1968 Cold War science
fiction film drama about competing American and Russian teams that
discover a flying saucer in Communist China. The film was
re-released in 1969 under the title Collision Course with an edited
down runtime of 90 minutes.

And:

Soon they are discovered by The Chinese Army, and after a wild
firefight when 2 Russians and 2 Americans and 1 Chinese (all 5 are
eventually killed) stand off the Chinese Army, killing at least 61
Chinese soldiers. The three survivors, two Americans and one of the
Russian scientists board the saucer, activate it, take off, and fly
out of Chinese airspace. A pre-programmed autopilot course instantly
takes control and flies them away from Earth past the Moon, past Mars,
and on a collision course with Saturn. Unable to return unless they
work together to control the alien UFO, they are finally successful
and able return to Earth in less than a minute. The trio decides to
land in Geneva, Switzerland. Then a quote from President John F.
Kennedy about mutual human cooperation in space flashes on screen.

It's on YouTube.



